# Include project's target libraries in CPack DEB package

Tags: cmake, cpack, cmakelists-options

I'm trying to use CPack to create a deb package from my c++ project.
I managed to generate and install the package, however, under `/opt/my_project/lib`, I cannot see the libraries my project depends on (Ceres for example). How can I pack the dependencies that I link as target_link_libraries?

I'm using CMake min required 3.16

Comment: This may be a use-case for [`install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#install-runtime-dependency-set).

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have not *tried* the things I'm suggesting. I'm just reading docs and looking for relevant material.

If the common repositories on the user-side include the required version of the dependency, take a look at:

- [`CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html#variable:CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS) and [`CPACK_DEBIAN_<COMPONENT>_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html#variable:CPACK_DEBIAN_%3CCOMPONENT%3E_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS)

  > May be set to ON in order to use `dpkg-shlibdeps` to generate better package dependency list.
- or [`CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html#variable:CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS) and [`CPACK_DEBIAN_<COMPONENT>_PACKAGE_DEPENDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html#variable:CPACK_DEBIAN_%3CCOMPONENT%3E_PACKAGE_DEPENDS).

  > Sets the Debian dependencies of this package.
  >
  > Note If `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS` or more specifically `CPACK_DEBIAN_<COMPONENT>_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS` is set for this component, the discovered dependencies will be appended to `CPACK_DEBIAN_<COMPONENT>_PACKAGE_DEPENDS` instead of `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS`. If `CPACK_DEBIAN_<COMPONENT>_PACKAGE_DEPENDS` is an empty string, only the automatically discovered dependencies will be set for this component.

Otherwise, you could look at shipping the dependency binaries with your binary using [`install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#install-runtime-dependency-set), but this is probably bad practice in the debian ecosystem, and probably has legal implications (and I am not a lawyer).